# Convert animated GIF to animated SVG and to get the code of SVG?

Tags: animated-gif, svg-animate

I have animated gif.However I would need to export to SVG format.Is it possible to convert an animated GIF to an animated SVG-image?
I want to export my gif as an Animated SVG so that I can use it on my website and Mobile Apps.

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid that can't be done directly. Animated GIFs are a sequence of bitmap images where in the images each pixel is defined, while SVGs are vector based, which means each object (line, shape) in the image is defined mathematically (and their animation is also defined mathematically).
To actually convert it, you would need to re-create your GIF in a vector-based editor like Adobe Illustrator (or have access to the source file if it was made in such an editor) and recreate the animations afterwards.